# Deleting columns in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How do I delete a column from an existing table?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove a column from an existing table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626344/how-to-remove-a-column-from-an-existing-table)

Comment: Actually, the other question was written 2 years after this one so that would be the duplicate.

Comment: Though the other question was written after this one it is getting way more views & votes. Must be a more google friendly title or something. As such I voted to close this question.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

The command you're looking for is:

```
alter table tblName drop column columnName
```

where `tblName` is the name of the table and `columnName` is the name of the column, but there's a few things you may need to do first.

- If there are any foreign key references to the column, you'll need to get rid of them first.
- If there's an index using that column, you'll need to either get rid of it or adjust it to not use that column.

---

Keep in mind that the performance of this command may not necessarily be good. One option is to wait for a down-time period when you can be certain no-one will be accessing the database, rename the current table, then use `create table` and `insert into ... select from` to transfer the columns you don't want deleted.

One of the later releases of Oracle actually has a soft delete which can just marks a column as unused without removing it physically. It has the same effect since you can no longer reference it and there's a command along the lines of `alter table ... drop unused columns` which is meant to be run in quiet time, which does the hard work of actually removing it physically.

This has the advantage of "disappearing" the columns immediately without dragging down database performance during busy times.

Answer (score 13):

`ALTER TABLE XXX DROP COLUMN YYY;`

Answer (score 5):

This can also be done through the SSMS GUI.

I like this method because it warns you if there are any relationships on that column and can also automatically delete those as well. As PaxDiablo states, if there are relationships, they must be deleted first.

1. Put table in Design view (right click on table) like so:

[image]

2. Right click on column in table's Design view and click "Delete
   Column"

[image]

At this point, if there are any relationships that would also need to be deleted, it will ask you if you would like to delete those as well.

Comment: After I had deleted the columns, I had to right click on the "Design" canvas, and select `Generate Change Script`. Then I ran that script which deleted the columns. The columns were not deleted before running that script.

Comment: @jeppoo1 OOC did you click Save after deleting the column?

Comment: I didn't, I wonder why that didn't even come to my mind... Now I know I can save it with CTRL+S! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For large tables this can be **very** slow. It can often be a lot faster to create a new table, a duplicate of the old one but with the changes, and insert the data. Drop the old table and then rename the new table.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE [Intake].[MER_SF_Opportunity_History] DROP COLUMN [[IntakeIsDeleted]]]
GO
```