# How do I delete a column in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

How do I delete a column in SQL Server 2005?

Comment: In your SO screen, on top right corner, you have a search text box. Try searching your question before you post!

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? Google?

Comment: @radkrish Do you see the Search box in the top right hand corner?  Please can **you** use it before claiming "duplicate!" (or better yet, post a link the the duplicate that answers this question)

Comment: @shahkalpesh Have **you** tried Google?  I have and all that comes up is a bunch of low quality links that a beginner might easily have trouble understanding.

Comment: oh ok ok......thanks for your information

Comment: As a beginner and Stackoverflow addicted.. I want **everything** on stackoverflow. Now as this question is on stackoverflow.. next time when a novice will search the same on google.. this link will be appeared to help him.

Comment: @Kragen: Here is how I searched (http://www.google.co.in/#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=delete+a+column+in+sql+server&aq=3&aqi=g4g-o1&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=f0e365a880e5c144). The 1st link has the answer to this. Can you show an example of how you searched to see low quality links?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deleting columns in MS SQL Server 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755544/deleting-columns-in-ms-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 7):

You can delete columns from a table using the [ALTER TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) command:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName DROP COLUMN columnName
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable DROP COLUMN MyColumnName
```

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of a previous answer - unless you have something else to add (and are going to edit this answer) then please could you delete it?

Comment: Ohhh ya. Possibly answer was posted at the same time. Not an issue. The main thing you get the idea thats it.

Comment: Less than 7 minutes, huh? What is that on eternity's scale?

Comment: @Kragen: Yoko Zunna always just copies other people's answers. Check out his other answers and run them through google - each one is a copy from stackoverflow or some blogpost.